# Probability that the last point is one of the three searched for?

Tags: probability

I can't wrap my head around this, although I believe it's a simple idea.

There are n points on a plane and with three of them we can build the smallest circle which contains all the other points. We inspect each point randomly, aka with the same probability, one after another and each time we compute the enclosing circle for all the points we inspected before.

What is the probability that the last point we inspect will be one of the three that we need to build the circle and why?

Comment: Isn't the asnwer $\frac 3n$ for trivial reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since three of the $n$ points will lie on the smallest circle that encompasses all of the other points, the probability that each (different) point inspected is one of these three, is $\frac3n$.  Hence also the probability that the *last* point inspected lies on the encompassing circle is $\frac3n$.